# Woocommerce variable products are being added to the card on the homepage (ajax)

Tags: php, theme-development, ajax, woocommerce-offtopic

Variable products **only on the homepage** are being added to the card instead of navigating to the product page when i press the select options button. I am using [tyche theme](https://colorlib.com/tyche/)

By default, Woocommerce ajax add to cart functionality is only supposed to apply to simple products  But for some reason it is also adding variable products to the cart when I click "Select Options."

Select Options is supposed to go to the product page. How can I disable ajax add to cart on variable products on the homepage of the theme?

Those products on the homepage are added using **Tyche Product** widget.

[My website sample](https://frixsample.mpoliasma.top/)

Comment: If you look at the markup you can see that your widget is outputting add to cart buttons. Unless you've added code somewhere else to modify add to cart buttons it sounds like your theme is doing something wrong. Questions about third-party plugins are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here though, so I'd suggest contacting the theme's support channels.

Comment: i did but they do not answer

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to fix this at the last 4 hours and **I got it**.
You need to change:
*ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button button*
**for this:**
*button product_type_variable add_to_cart_button* on the follow archives:

```
wp-content/themes/tyche/inc/libraries/widgets/widget-tyche-products/view/layout-a.php
wp-content/themes/tyche/inc/libraries/widgets/widget-tyche-products/view/layout-b.php
wp-content/themes/tyche/inc/libraries/widgets/widget-tyche-products/view/layout-c.php
wp-content/themes/tyche/inc/libraries/widgets/widget-tyche-products/view/layout-d.php
```

Its located between lines 60~90. You need to change in every archive.

Sorry for my bad English.

Love the community, so helpful <3

Good lucky for all !